# com.parse.PushService. How to catch exceptions?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

1. I need to catch any errors of com.parse.PushService. How can I do that? In my code I can catch any exception using

Example:

```
try {
  // some code
} catch (Throwable t) {
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

For example, need to catch errors as follows, and any others

```
    01-21 02:52:49.665: W/System.err(20407): java.lang.RuntimeException: You must call Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret) before using the Parse library.
01-21 02:52:49.670: W/System.err(20407):    at com.parse.ParseUser.checkApplicationContext(ParseUser.java:1196)
01-21 02:52:49.670: W/System.err(20407):    at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:970)
01-21 02:52:49.670: W/System.err(20407):    at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentSessionToken(ParseUser.java:1041)
01-21 02:52:49.670: W/System.err(20407):    at com.parse.ParsePush.sendInBackground(ParsePush.java:365)
```

Comment: The question is not so clear. Can you show the code you have now and what you want to improve?

Comment: This exception is straight forward and doesn't really need to be caught, the solution to the problem can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796778/you-must-call-parse-initialize-before-using-parse-library-on-android

Comment: but if for some reason you want to catch this exception you need to put your try/catch around every parse call because this exception is thrown when you try to use parse functionality without initializing it first.

Comment: The error is clear Declare the Parse.initialize(context, oauthKey, oauthSecret)

Comment: Yes, I'm not called Parse.initialize at app start time, because I want start initialization at specified time (after user will fill all necessary data)

Comment: The initialization doesn't take user input, read the docs and implement it correctly. Most errors come back as json responses, very rarely have I encountered parse exceptions but you can find a list of exceptions here: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseException.html

Comment: But what if I want to put some data in installation table?

Comment: You still need to initialize once your app starts then you just put data in the installation and save it in the background, the initialize has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks very much. Please post your first comment as answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is straight forward and doesn't really need to be caught, the solution to the problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796778/) or below.

First extend Application with your own class.

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
  }
}
```

Make sure to declare it in the manifest as well

```
<application
    android:name="yourpackagename.App"
.
.
.
</application>
```