# parse does not push notifications but it shows registered users

Tags: android, parse-platform

The parse does not push notifications to the users. But it shows the registered users in the site.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

ParseApplication.java

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxxx", "xxxx");

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

ParseReceiver.java

```
public class ParseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

  private final String TAG = "Parse Notification";
  private String msg = "";
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Log.i(TAG, "PUSH RECEIVED!!!");

    try {
        String action = arg1.getAction();
        String channel = arg1.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
        JSONObject json = new   JSONObject(arg1.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
        Iterator itr = json.keys();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
            if(key.equals("string")){
                msg = json.getString(key);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }


    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(arg0.getResources(),
            R.drawable.happy);

    Intent launchActivity = new Intent(arg0, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, launchActivity, 0);

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(arg0)
    .setContentTitle("PUSH RECEIVED")
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.happy)
    .setLargeIcon(icon)
    .setContentIntent(pi)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(0, noti);
     }


     }
```

Receiver.java

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver{

   @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(arg0,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(arg1.getExtras());
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    arg0.startActivity(i);

   }
   }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.parse"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"   />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 < uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
  android:name="com.example.parse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.parse.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="com.example.parse.ParseApplication" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.parse.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.example.parse.Receiver"
        android:exported="false"  >

            <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
  </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action   android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.example.parse"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796778/you-must-call-parse-initialize-before-using-parse-library-on-android

Comment: Sorry...I can't understand..