# I want to use Nuxt with parse javascript client

Tags: parse-server, nuxt.js

I installed nuxt as **PWA** then I installed parse client from

```
npm i nuxt-parse
```

after that i added in **nuxt.config.js**

```
 ['nuxt-parse', {
      appID: "blablabla",
      javascriptKey: "blablabla",
      serverUrl: "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
  }
```

after that when i use

```
this.$parse.User.logIn('username', 'password'))
```

it returns `Error: You need to call Parse.initialize before using Parse.`

please any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You must call Parse.initialize() before using Parse library on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796778/you-must-call-parse-initialize-before-using-parse-library-on-android)

Comment: In your cloud code, remove any definition of Parse. Do not require parse. It is pre-initialized and available to you as a Global and must not be re-defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11960598/joseph thanks for your reply but it isn't  like android nuxt.js is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue when changed  name of appid from appID to appId this is an issue in this pod

**from**`['nuxt-parse', {
      appID: "blablabla",
      javascriptKey: "blablabla",
      serverUrl: "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
  }`

**to**`['nuxt-parse', {
      appId: "blablabla",
      javascriptKey: "blablabla",
      serverUrl: "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
  }`